# Sci Fi Short story with girl at futuristic movie theater being kept from seeing a movie uncovers conspiracy by film companies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was sci-fi short story or novella that I read in Analog, Asimov's or SF&F in the past decade or so.

Set in a future extrapolation of our social-media, fan-centered world inside a future mega movie theater entertainment mall, where a late high school/ early college aged girl is with a group of friends and she really wants to see a certain movie and is consistently and conveniently redirected from seeing the one she is interested in. She ends up becoming intrigued by a boy at the theater acting strangely and becomes involved in the undercover "kid's" mission within the theater. The premise is that so many movies were being made, that a conspiracy formed where some movie companies started to advertise and market movies and merchandise for movies that they never *actually* filmed, and they were getting away with it.

Comment: I read this, I think it was in a "Years best Si-fi" anthology. The "boy" was actually an undercover agent she had previously dated.

Comment: I'm sure I saw a story like that in 'The Simpsons'!

Comment: That would be a better world than our _current_ world where they, sadly, _do_ go ahead and make the movies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIRC this is ["Now Showing"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1711545) by Connie Willis. You could read it in GRRM's anthology Rogues or Mrs Willis' new Christmas stories collection.

Comment: Could you edit to explain how this matches the OPs description?

Comment: The Google book at https://books.google.com/books?id=AjUGAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT848&lpg=PT848#v=onepage&q&f=false has most of the text of the story.

Comment: That was it. Thanks. Weird I remembered this as being something I read much longer ago and from a mag as opposed to an anthology, but checked my copy and sure 'nuff. Thanks again!